# Divide a line of image into two equal parts using flex layout

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I have 8 logos.I made an interface and an array in typescript file. Images are showing in one line. But I want to show these into two equal parts. First line will take four and second line too. So, I have to use angular flex layout.

[N.B]: I used fxLayout="row wrap". But it is showing 3 3 2 in this formation.

HTML:

```
<div  
    fxLayout="row" 
    fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" 
    fxLayoutGap="1rem"
    >

      <ng-container *ngFor="let iconAttribute of iconAttributes">
        <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutGap="1rem">
          <img [src]="iconAttribute.imageAttribute" alt="iconAttribute.nameAttributre" width="120">
          <p>{{ iconAttribute.nameAttributre }}</p>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
      
    </div>
  </mat-card>
```

Comment: You mean you want two lines of four images ?

Comment: @Emilien Yes, Two lines of four images. Thanks for your concern. But I solved it by myself. Using fxLayout="row wrap" and fxFlex="25%" I did it. I don't know if there is any better solution. But It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" fxLayoutGap="1rem">
<ng-container *ngFor="let iconAttribute of iconAttributes" fxFlex="50">
```

Comment: Elaborate on how it resolves the OP's issue.

Comment: @Xenikh did you asked me how I solved? :|

Comment: No I didn't asked you, but the person who has written the answer.